# Make the TaskScheduler synchronously and run in the main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, taskfactory

I'm looking for a way to create a TaskScheduler that runs synchronously in the main thread to allow WPF applications to be configured as single thread for debugging purpose.

Any idea?

For now I'm using the sample [LimitedTaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) on MSDN that allow to specify the concurrency level (how many threads use) and this extension to set the static TaskFactory before the application starts:

```
void SetOnTaskFactory(TaskFactory taskFactory)
{
    const BindingFlag = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic
    var field = typeof(Task).GetField("s_factory", BindingFlag);
    field.SetValue(null, taskFactory);
}
```

Comment: maybe var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); ?

Comment: It doesn't work, if you do in that way you receive an InvalidOperationException, you need to create a SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext()), but the code runs in a secondary thread.

Comment: Is that code executed inside unit tests? It should work if your app is running.. For unit test, take a look at the CurrentThreadTaskScheduler , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! It works using the CurrentThreadTaskScheduler. If you answer to the question I set your as the correct.

Comment: glad it works, i posted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing purposes you can use the [`CurrentThreadTaskScheduler`](https://github.com/donatasm/ParallelExtensionsExtras/blob/master/src/TaskSchedulers/CurrentThreadTaskScheduler.cs) from [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) library.
Basically it's a simple `TaskScheduler` that executes all tasks on the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a SynchronousTaskScheduler, you can do so using below code.

```
void Main()
{
    SynchronousTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new SynchronousTaskScheduler();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeMethod(i), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
    }
}

void SomeMethod(int number)
{
    $"Scheduled task {number}".Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class SynchronousTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(
        Task task,
        bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs one at a time but won't isolate tasks to the same thread